# Import whole module to Python/Django project

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-import

I need to import whole custom module (`config.py`) to `settings.py` file. Both on the same folder.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr8s7.png)

It works fine when I use `from .config import var`

**BUT**

`import config` or `import .config` gives *no module* or *invalid syntax* error.

Is there way to import whole module to Django files?

Comment: `from . import config`

Comment: @Adelin It works! Thank you.

Comment: @Adelin Don't answer in comments please.

Comment: @9769953 don't answer duplicated questions please

Comment: @Adelin Then please mark it as a duplicate; I found it hard to find a proper duplicate, since most questions (and answers) deal with similar but not the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
from . import config
```

for a relative import of the whole module.